# How to do Transfer Learning with LSTM for time series forecasting?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, transfer-learning

I am working on a project about time-series forecasting using LSTMs layers. The dataset used for training and testing the model was collected among 443 persons which worn a sensor that samples a physical variable ( 1 variable/measure) every 5 minutes, for each patient there are around 5000 records/readings.

Although, I can train and test my model under different scenarios, I am troubled finding information about how to apply transfer learning in such an architecture. I mean, I understand I can use inductive transfer-learning by copying the matrix-weights from the general model onto a secondary model (unknown person), then after I can re-train this model with specific data and evaluate the result.

But I would like to know if somebody knows other ways to apply transfer-learning on this type of architecture or where to find information about it since there aren't many scientific papers talking about it, mostly they talk about NLP and other type of application but time series?
Cheers X )